# GemfireTemplate with ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY_HEAP_LRU doesn't cache locally

Tags: spring-boot, gemfire, spring-cache, spring-data-gemfire, geode

`clientCache.createClientRegionFactory(ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY_HEAP_LRU)` works as expected when used with a `spring-cache` `GemfireCacheManager` and caches data locally.

 However when the same settings is used in conjunction with `GemfireTemplate`, to use Gemfire as a repo instead of a cache, doesn't seem to be caching data locally *at all* and always fetches back from server. 
 I'm storing value as a small Hashmap and have tried increasing heap memory to `-Xms1024m -Xmx2148m` to nullify the effect of less heap memory with no effect.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First, why would you (possibly?) be using GemFire's API to create a client Region with [`ClientCache.createClientRegionFactory(:ClientRegionShortcut)`](http://gemfire-92-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/client/ClientCache.html#createClientRegionFactory-org.apache.geode.cache.client.ClientRegionShortcut-), especially in a *Spring* context?  To properly manage the lifecycle of GemFire objects in a *Spring* context, you you should be using *Spring Data GemFire*, and SDG's configuration, either [XML](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#bootstrap) or (preferably) [Annotation-based](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config).

Second, this...

> *However when the same settings is used in conjunction with GemfireTemplate, to use Gemfire as a repo instead of a cache, **doesn't seem to be** caching data locally at all and always fetches back from server.*

Is rather weak argument.  What makes you think it "***doesn't seem to be***" caching data locally?

Have you observed output in GemFire's log to support your claim?  Have you written a test to confirm your assumption?  What is your *Spring* (?) configuration to configure GemFire in a *Spring* context along with acquiring access to the Region via the `GemfireTemplate`?  What version of Spring Data GemFire are you using? Etc, etc.

Do you understand that the `GemfireTemplate` is a [wrapper for a GemFire Region](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.html#GemfireTemplate-org.apache.geode.cache.Region-) (which uses the *Template Software Design Pattern*, serving the same purpose as *Spring's* [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html))?  Any [`GemfireTemplate.put(key, value)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.html#put-K-V-) operation effectively [calls `Region.put(key, value)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.1.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.java#L188).

> NOTE: Using various *Spring* template's enables your application's data access operations to be conveniently decorated with additional capabilities, such as translating data store-specific Exceptions (e.g. GemFire, and often erroneously "Checked" Exceptions) in *Spring's* all important Data Access [Exception Hierarchy](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#dao-exceptions) along with enabling your application data access operations to properly participate in a Transaction when inside a Transactional scope, without having to write boilerplate code like `tx.begin()` and either `tx.commit()` or `tx.rollback()`.  Anyway...

So, even if your code look somewhat like this...

```
RegionFactory exampleRegionFactory = clientCache.createClientRegionFactory(ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY_HEAP_LRU);

// 1. call various setters to configure the Region created by the factory
exampleRegionFacatory.set...
...

// 2. create the Region
Region exampleRegion = exampleRegionFactory.create("Example");

// 3. interface to the Region via the GemfireTemplate
GemfireTemplate exampleTemplate = new GemfireTemplate(exampleRegion);

// 4. put key/value into /Example Region
examleTemplate.put("myKey", "myValue");
```

How is that any different than, instead of 4, just this...

```
exampleRegion.put("myKey", "myValue");
```

And finally, consider this [test class](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/ClientCacheRegionDataAccessUsingGemfireTemplateIntegrationTests.java) I wrote...

This test class is [based on](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/pom.xml#L56) *Spring Data GemFire* 2.0.1.RELEASE.

This test class [includes a Gfsh shell script](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/ClientCacheRegionDataAccessUsingGemfireTemplateIntegrationTests.java#L53-L61) to start up a small GemFire cluster (a Locator and Server) and to inspect the server after each test run, if you prefer.  However, in order to inspect the state of the server after a test run, you will need to comment out [this line](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/ClientCacheRegionDataAccessUsingGemfireTemplateIntegrationTests.java#L100).  But then, you must remember to wipe the data on the server before your next test run using `remove --region=/Example --key=testKey` otherwise, [this assertion](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/ClientCacheRegionDataAccessUsingGemfireTemplateIntegrationTests.java#L115) will **fail**, obviously!

As you can see, I have the client [Region data policy set with the `ClientRegionShort.CACHING_PROXY_HEAP_LRU`](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/ClientCacheRegionDataAccessUsingGemfireTemplateIntegrationTests.java#L78) (as you stated above).  You can experiment with different `ClientRegionShortcuts` to see their effect.  This test class will pass with all `ClientRegionShortcuts` except for `ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY` (which, of course, does not store any data "locally" in the client's Region, therefore has **NO** size).  With the `LOCAL`-only based `ClientRegionShortcuts`, you don't need to run a server.

finally, I have created 2 *Spring* Profiles, the [*Spring Data GemFire* Annotation-based configuration approach](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/ClientCacheRegionDataAccessUsingGemfireTemplateIntegrationTests.java#L138-L153) (Profile "*Spring Data GemFire*"), along with the [GemFire API-based approach](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/ClientCacheRegionDataAccessUsingGemfireTemplateIntegrationTests.java#L155-L177) (Profile "**GemFireApi**").  Don't ever use the later, especially in a *Spring* context.  I wrote this profile to purely demonstrate that if you are using the snippet of client Region configuration from above, it will still work!

You can switch profiles using the *Spring* `TestContext` `@ActiveProfiles` annotation, [like so](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/ClientCacheRegionDataAccessUsingGemfireTemplateIntegrationTests.java#L74).

One last thing to note, the `Region.size()` method only consider the local (client) Region's size as [explained in the Javadoc](http://gemfire-92-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html#size--), where as the `Region.sizeOnServer()` will inspect the corresponding (by name) server Region's size ([Javadoc](http://gemfire-92-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html#sizeOnServer--)).

This test **passes as expected**!

Hope this helps!

-John